# Haskell error: Variable not in scope

Tags: haskell

I'm a bit new to Haskell but I've been working this problem for a couple hours with no luck.

I'm trying to implement something similar to a filter, except a predicate and list is passed to a function and it returns a tuple of two lists, one which is filtered by the predicate and one which is not.

```
divideList :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
divideList p xs = (f, nf) where 
f = doFilter p xs
nf = doFilter (not . p) xs

doFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
doFilter _ [] = []
doFilter p (x:xs) = [x | p x] ++ doFilter p xs
```

The second function, `doFilter` works properly. It applies the filter to its list and spits out the appropriate list. (i.e. If I just use `doFilter (>3) [1,2,3,4,5,6]` it will work properly)

My issue is with the first function. When I use `divideList (>3) [1,2,3,4,5,6]` I get a number of `Variable not in scope` errors. The errors are listed below:

```
AddListOperations.hs:20:23: error:
    Variable not in scope: p :: a -> Bool

AddListOperations.hs:20:25: error: Variable not in scope: xs :: [a]

AddListOperations.hs:21:31: error:
    Variable not in scope: p :: a -> Bool

AddListOperations.hs:21:34: error: Variable not in scope: xs :: [a]
```

Like I said, I have only been messing around with Haskell for a few days so let me know if I'm leaving out any important information.

Comment: You need to indent `f = ...` and `nf = ...` otherwise there is no way of knowing they are attached to `divideList`.

Comment: I can't believe this is all it took... thank you so much

Comment: BTW, [Hoogle would have told you](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%28%5Ba%5D%2C%5Ba%5D%29) that `partition` is the function you want.

Answer (score 2):

Indent both `f` and `nf`:

```
divideList :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
divideList p xs = (f, nf) where
  f  = doFilter p xs
  nf = doFilter (not . p) xs
```

After all, where would your `where` block stop?

By the way, `divideList` is `partition` from `Data.List`.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized that all I needed was some indentation. Does partition separate lists based on a predicate (a la filter)?

Comment: [Yes.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alec, I found that all I needed to do was indent the statements underneath `where`:

```
divideList :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
divideList p xs = (f, nf) where 
    f = doFilter p xs
    nf = doFilter (not . p) xs
```